# How can I edit a parent's property from a view in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

These are the classes of my model:

```
/// <summary>
/// States the base implementation for all document lines in a purchasing module.
/// </summary>
public class DocumentLine : Keyed
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Document number of the document line.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ApplicationResources), Name = "DocumentNumber")]
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And:

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines a line of a Delivery Note document.
/// </summary>
[MetadataType(typeof(DeliveryNoteLineMetadata))]
public class DeliveryNoteLine : DocumentLine
{
   ...
    /// <summary>
    /// Internal class for metadata.
    /// </summary>
    internal class DeliveryNoteLineMetadata
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds the RequiredAttribute to the inherited DocumentNumber property.
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here part of the Edit.cshtml's View code:

```
<div class="display-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DocumentNumber)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DocumentNumber, new { @placeholder = @ApplicationResources.DocumentNumber })
</div>
```

This is my controller's method

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the POST event for the Edit action, updating an existing TEntity object.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">Id of the TEntity object to update.</param>
/// <param name="model">TEntity object with properties updated.</param>
/// <returns>Redirection to the Index action if succeeded, the Edit View otherwise.</returns>
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(string id, TEntity model)
{
    var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(Resource + "?id={id}", RestSharp.Method.PUT) { RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json }
        .AddParameter("id", id, RestSharp.ParameterType.UrlSegment)
        .AddBody(model);
    var response = Client.Execute(request);

    // Handle response errors
    HandleResponseErrors(response);

    if (Errors.Length == 0)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Errors = Errors;
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

This is not working. The value for the property DocumentNumber of the DocumentLine object doesn't change and It's being hard to me to understand how the MVC4 controller work inside.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you posting the changed values back to your controller method? If so what does your controller method look like?

Comment: Can you please check in your output HTML what is the ID and Name properties of that textbox? MVC maps the Entity passed on to the controller through these names. If the name is wrong it might be that you need to set it up manually in the CSHTML.

Comment: The output HTML seems to be correct:
<input id="DocumentNumber" type="text" value="XXXXX" placeholder="DocumentNumber" name="DocumentNumber">

Comment: Are you editing a single DeliveryNoteLine or a few at the same time? If you have a few being edited at the time, you're missing the array index.

Also, what is the TEntity in the controller?

Comment: Fixed. Everything was OK, but there was an input type="hidden" with the value and the controller was taking that value instead of the one in the editor-field. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

First, have `DeliveryNoteLineMetadata` inherit from `DocumentLine`:

```
internal class DeliveryNoteLineMetadata : DocumentLine
```

Then just change the getter and setter to use the base value (also adding `new` to hide the `base` property):

```
[Required]
public new string DocumentNumber 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return base.DocumentNumber;
    }
    set
    {
        base.DocumentNumber = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It says that 'object' does not contain a definition for DocumentNumber. :S

Comment: @Kutyel, Apologies, you need the `new` keyword to hide the base property. Also, you need `DeliveryNoteLineMetadata` to inherit from `DocumentLine`. See my edit

Comment: I'm afraid this solution is not working :'( When I debug the value of the deliveryNote, the base properties, including the DocumentNumber, never changes. >_<